# Why does window.location.href not complete the $.post...?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a game for class and as with most games users are required to complete a level before moving on to the next. On my first level I use this under the `If` statement that determines if the user has won the level:

```
if (passOnLevel == 0 && passengerCarrying == 0) {
    alert("You Win!");
    $.post("gameL2.php", {"Level1": "Level1"});
    window.location.href='gameL2.php';
}
```

In my `gameL2.php` file I have this at the top of the file:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Level1'])) {
$_SESSION['Level1'] = $_POST['Level1'];
}
 ?>
```

The issue I am having is that when I use `window.location.href='gameL2.php;` the $_POST is not set however if I removed `window.location.href='gameL2.php;` it doesn't redirect the user to the next level but when I access the `gameL2.php` file directly the $_POST is set. How can I make it redirect the users to level two but still set the post variable?

Comment: _“How can I make it redirect the users to level two but still set the post variable?”_ – only by send a _form_ with method=POST. Your AJAX request and the changing of the location are two _different_ requests, the latter one being a GET request. And AJAX runs in the background, so it does not change the URL the user is on – you can’t have both at the same time.

Comment: `$.post` is *asynchronous*!  It runs in the background, while the rest of your code continues.  `window.location.href` doesn't wait until it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `$.post` is asynchronous command, so when you call it, you are calling `location.href` right afterwards and `$.post` did not have time to actually do the post.

So what you need to do is this:

```
if (passOnLevel == 0 && passengerCarrying == 0) {
    alert("You Win!");
    $.post("gameL2.php", {"Level1": "Level1"}, function() {
      window.location.href='gameL2.php';
    });
}
```

Basically you are passing a function that `$.post` will call when it finishes. More at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

BUt, this will not resolve your problem with $_POST being unset in the second file, because calling $.post and opening gameL2.php are two calls, and data sending does not work that way.

So, in the end, you would probably be best off with:

```
if (passOnLevel == 0 && passengerCarrying == 0) {
    alert("You Win!");
    window.location.href='gameL2.php?Level1=Level1';
}
```

And then checking for `$_GET["Level1"]` in your gameL2.php

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was something to do with it not being able to finish but I didn't know how to do it (now I do :)).